# scrollable material ui chips array using arrow buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to build custom scrollable chips array with material ui *version 4 no version 5*.

In older tickets i could see similar demos:
[Demo code](https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-material-ui-chips-single-line-with-scroll-244xx?file=/src/App.js)

I want to change this component scrolling bar to left and right arrow buttons (same line with the Chip array).

please suggest how it can be done by modifying the same code or advice on another approach.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use Material UI `Tabs`

[image: Edit geocoding-demo (forked)]

And style scroll Buttons using `.MuiTabs-scrollButtons` class name.
Or change scroll buttons using `Tabs`'s prop: `ScrollButtonComponent`.

[Material UI Tabs Documentation](https://v4.mui.com/api/tabs/)

Comment: Actually this working but there is error even in your sandbox

Comment: I fixed errors in  sandbox, Check it again, please 
Александър К.

Comment: Thanks! How you fixed it? Because I'm integrating it in my project and I had the same error.

Comment: 1- Relace `<Li>` with `<Tab>` and put your custom component in `label` prop.                 
2- Add `value={false}` to `Tabs` to avoid `The value provided to the Tabs component is invalid.` error

Comment: If you want to select multiple chips simultaneously tabs are not good choice.

Answer (score 0):

@Amr Thanks for the advice, I have now exactly what I need.
I can't share the full code because it's mixed a lot with other code that is not related to this question, but here is something similar that I can share:

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Chip from "@material-ui/core/Chip";
import Box from "@material-ui/core/Box";
import Tabs from "@material-ui/core/Tabs";
import IconButton from "@material-ui/core/IconButton";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";
import ChevronLeftIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeftRounded";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRightRounded";

const StyledChip = styled(Chip)`
  border-radius: 16px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  color: ${(props) => (props.selected ? "#FFFFFF" : "#6877AE")};
  background-color: ${(props) => (props.selected ? "#03194F" : "#FFFFFF")};
  border: 4px solid ${"#03194F"};
  border-color: ${(props) =>
    props.selected ? "#03194F" : "rgba(0, 83, 229, 0.12)"};

  .MuiChip-root&:hover {
    background-color: ${(props) => (props.selected ? "#03194F" : "")};
  }
`;

const StyledIconButton = styled(IconButton)`
  left: ${(props) => (props.isLeft ? "0" : "none")};
  right: ${(props) => (props.isLeft ? "none" : "0")};

  height: 32px;
  width: 32px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 16px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  //top: 33%;
  background-color: white;
  color: rgba(0, 83, 229, 1);
  border-color: rgba(0, 83, 229, 0.12);

  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 20px;

  :hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
      0px 4px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0px 1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-color: white;
    background-color: inherit;
  }
`;

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    flexWrap: "nowrap",
    listStyle: "none",
    padding: theme.spacing(0.5),
    margin: 0,
    overflow: "auto",
    maxWidth: "100%"
  },
  chip: {
    margin: theme.spacing(2)
  }
}));

export default function ChipsArray() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [chipData, setChipData] = React.useState([
    { key: 0, label: "Angular" },
    { key: 1, label: "jQuery" },
    { key: 2, label: "Polymer" },
    { key: 3, label: "React" },
    { key: 4, label: "Vue" },
    { key: 5, label: "Knockout" },
    { key: 6, label: "Ember" },
    { key: 7, label: "D3" },
    { key: 8, label: "Google Charts" },
    { key: 9, label: "C+" },
    { key: 10, label: "C++" },
    { key: 11, label: "NodeJS" }
  ]);

  const [selectedIndustryFilter, setSelectedIndustryFilter] = React.useState(
    "Angular"
  );

  return (
    <Box className={classes.root}>
      <Tabs
        variant="scrollable"
        scrollButtons="on"
        aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
        ScrollButtonComponent={(props) => {
          if (props.direction === "left") {
            return (
              <StyledIconButton isLeft {...props}>
                <ChevronLeftIcon />
              </StyledIconButton>
            );
          } else if (props.direction === "right") {
            return (
              <StyledIconButton {...props}>
                <ChevronRightIcon />
              </StyledIconButton>
            );
          } else {
            return null;
          }
        }}
      >
        {chipData.map((data) => {
          return (
            <StyledChip
              label={data.label}
              onClick={() => {
                setSelectedIndustryFilter(data.label);
                console.log(data.label);
              }}
              selected={data.label === selectedIndustryFilter}
              key={data.key}
              className={classes.chip}
            />
          );
        })}
      </Tabs>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

also you can check it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/demo-material-ui-chips-single-line-with-scroll-forked-2f0z30?file=/src/index.js